# CSS: 2 divs next to each other, one floated right, the other needs to be centered in the remaining space

Tags: css, html

I have 2 divs next to each other.
The wrapper size is width:100%.
The right aligned div is 230px.
The div that is next to the right aligned one needs to be centered in the container to remain responsive.
The left margin was just temporary because it was hugging the left aligned div.

CSS

```
.wrapper{
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.col-browse{
float: left;
width: 230px;
}

.col-content{
float: left;
width: 1080px;
margin-left: 30px;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-browse">
</div>  
<div class="col-content">
</div>
```

Thanks!

EDIT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUYdE.jpg
This is what im getting and i need the middle part to be centered while keeping the left column snapped to left

Comment: Can you post an image of the output you want?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/8Y7XXAx.png

Comment: I need the middle part to be centered

Comment: Centered relative to window or container?

Comment: Centered to window I suppose. Id like to try both. but prefereably window

Comment: I added an answer.Check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **CSS** below:

```
html,body,.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper{
    position:relative;
}

.col-browse{
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    width: 230px;
}

.col-content{
    text-align:center;
    width: 1080px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4G9sM/1/)

---

If you want it to be centered in all screen sizes then try following fiddle:

### [Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/4G9sM/6/) (<kbd>Updated</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

you can try the below css code.

```
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.col-browse{
  float: right;
  width: 18%;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  height: 100px;
}
.col-content{
  width: 82%;
  margin:0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define width of container of where element will be centered within (this element `position: relative;` centered element will simply be inside of previous mentioned and `margin: 0 auto;` have div which is not to be within container (right div), simply `float:right;` outside of.

Answer (score 0):

The following example could help you achieve the `style` you want

the `CSS`

```
.l,.r{
width:30%;
height:200px;
background:red;
}

.l{
float:right;
}

.r{
margin:0 auto;
}

.wrap{
float:left;
width:70%;
background:blue;
}
```

the `html`

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="r"></div>
</div>
<div class="l"></div>
```

working Example [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/H2Fzw/)

Answer (score 0):

try using relative values (percent), this will help you to create a responsive website. The example:

http://jsfiddle.net/XkPay/

```
.wrapper{
width: 100%;
}

.col-browse{
float: left;
width: 18%;
background-color:black;
}

.col-content{
float: left;
width: 82%;
    background-color:red;
 }
```

Comment: Is this what the OP was asking for? Probably not.

Answer (score 0):

probably this is what you need..
[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hw4EN/)

```
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height:500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:Yellow;
}

.col-browse{
     float: left;
     width: 20%;
     height:500px;
     background-color:Red;
}

.col-content{
    width: 80%;
    height:500px;
    margin-left:21%;
    background-color:Blue;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This attempt keeps the width of the sidebar and the width of the centered content constant.

**HTML**

```
<div class="right">
    <div class="center"></div>
</div>
<div class="left"></div>
```

---

### Centered to window

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yNLrQ/3)</kbd>

**CSS**

```
div.left {
    float: left;
    width: 230px;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
div.right {
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
div.center {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

---

### Centered to column

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yNLrQ/)</kbd>

**CSS**

```
div.left {
    float: left;
    width: 230px;
    height: 20px;
}
div.right {
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 230px;
}
div.center {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

---

**Note:** I would recommend centered to column, personal design preference. If you center to window the blank space would be off-balance. Again, just my opinion.